# How use :private-members: to show mangled member value constants in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, private-members, autodoc

How can I get the value of a constant into my Sphinx documentation?

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
  :members:
  :private-members:
```

This is my test module:

```
class Test:
  """My Test Class"""

  __MY_TEST_CONSTANT = 98.2
  """My test constant docu"""
```

At the moment I get the description of my private constant but the value is "None" and not "98.2".

```
class Test: 
  My Test Class


  __MY_TEST_CONSTANT = None
  My test constant docu
```

Comment: Does anything change if the name of the constant starts with a single underscore?

Comment: Yes with a single underscore, the value is shown as expected.

Comment: I asked because with two leading underscores, I get two constants in the output: one with a "mangled" name (`_module__MY_TEST_CONSTANT = 98.2`) and the one that you mention (`__MY_TEST_CONSTANT = None`).

Comment: @mzjn perhaps I should report this on github?

Comment: @bad_coder: Perhaps. This looks similar to https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1362

Comment: @user5580578 I think the best (pragmatic) alternatives to workaround this problem (at the moment) are using `annotation` if there's nothing against hard coding the value in your rst. Or, document object explicitly using the "mangled" name in rst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and I'm pretty sure it's either: an undocumented feature, a bug, or both. For example,

your_module.py

```py
class YourClass:
    """Your class."""

    _one_cls = 11.1  #: one class
    __two_cls = 22.2  #: two class
    __three_cls__ = 33.3  #: three class
    four_cls_ = 44.4  #: four class
```

your_module.rst

```
your_module
===========

.. automodule:: your_module
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :private-members:
```

results in having both  "mangled" `_YourClass__two_cls` and " not mangled" `__two_cls`, however only the "mangled" member has the value.

[image]

Now lets try documenting each object individually using sphinx directives:

your_module.rst

```
your_module
===========

.. automodule:: your_module
    :exclude-members: YourClass

    .. autoclass:: YourClass
      :members: 
      :show-inheritance:
      :private-members: 
      :exclude-members: _one_cls, four_cls_, __two_cls, _YourClass__two_cls

        .. autoattribute:: _one_cls

        .. autoattribute:: _YourClass__two_cls

        ..
            including this would yield an error:
            .. autoattribute:: __two_cls
            > failed to import attribute 'YourClass.__two_cls' from module 'your_module'

        .. autoattribute:: four_cls_
```

results in:

[image]

Here 2 noteworthy aspects can be verified that hint at a bug.

1. By explicitly including the "mangled" `_YourClass__two_cls` the HTML is different from the first version, now it gets "wrapped" in a `blockquote` and because of that the indent also shows differently.
2. If you try to explicitly the `.. autoattribute:: __two_cls` Sphinx issues the following warning:

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import attribute 'YourClass.__two_cls' from module 'your_module'; the following exception was raised:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "===========\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 307, in safe_getattr
>      return getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
>   AttributeError: type object 'YourClass' has no attribute '__two_cls'

Because Sphinx imports the Python objects the member `__two_cls'` will already be "mangled" before the document generation step starts. Sphinx is actually correct in this, documenting the "not mangled" member would lead documentation readers to a false expectation.